# C# connect to IIS Server and compare Server Website folder and Client Folder on local Machine

Tags: c#

How to connect server already hosted on IIS Website Folder and compare the Local Client Folder?

This is my Website URL on localhost

```
 IISHostedWebsite/Updates         //Folder in Website
```

I need to compare in this url update folder files with my local client machine's `D:\Updates` folder.

If new updates available into server it will copy to my `D:\Updates` folder.

How can we achieve this sort of situation ?

I have some code that in C#

```
 var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\Anand\\Work\\FolderCheck\\Server");
 var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
               orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
               select f).First();
```

This code generates the latest updated file from folder

Comment: I think it's better allways have a xml or something with the file's versions and on the client machine. Then you only have to check the XML (or the file) and copy the files with different verions. Anyway lets checkout a solution for your problem.

Comment: Sir i have Folder on Client Machin Which is i need to Updated Files from Server and Copy into Client Machine. How can i go for this situation in C# ?

Answer (score 2):

The MSDeploy tool (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) was designed to solve this problem.  It lets you compare IIS virtual directories to other directories, and synchronize them if needed.  It can also be used just as a diff tool.

In your example, after installing MSDeploy, you could do the following:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="IISHostedWebSite/Updates" -dest:contentPath=d:\updates -whatIf
```

This command will show the list of changes needed to update d:\updates to look like IISHostedWebSites/Updates.  If you remove the "-whatif" it will actually do the changes.

You can also call the MSDeploy programatically to do the same thing.

Also the problem with your code snippet is that you wouldn't detect deleted files from source that also need to be deleted from destination.

Answer (score 0):

> Here my code is for Getting Files from Directory and Check Whether are same if not It will Showing No updates Found and After that It will Check latest Files Available into Folder if Available then Copy this Files and Move to Destination Folder This is my Task but i have completed my code in Latest updated file i get from this code but i dont no how this files are copy into destination folder

```
 string serverPath = @"D:\Anand\Work\FolderCheck\Server";    //Source File
 string clientPath = @"D:\Anand\Work\FolderCheck\Client";   //destination Folder



  private static bool CompareFileSizes(string fileServer, string fileClient)
    {
        bool fileSizeEqual = true;

        if (fileServer.Length == fileClient.Length)  // Compare file sizes
        {
            fileSizeEqual = false;        // File sizes are not equal therefore files are not identical
        }
        return fileSizeEqual;
    }

 try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(serverPath) || !File.Exists(clientPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    var Server = Path.GetFileName(serverPath);
                    var Client = Path.GetFileName(clientPath);

                    string ServerFile = Server.ToString();
                    string ClientFile = Client.ToString();

                    if (CompareFileSizes(ServerFile, ClientFile))
                    {
                        lblServerMsg.Text = "No Updates are Found: ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var directoryServer = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Anand\Work\FolderCheck\Server"); //check latest Available File From Server                          
                        var myFile = (from f in directoryServer.GetFiles()
                                      orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                                      select f).First();


                        lblServerMsg.Text = "Updates Are Available Click for Update Button:";
                        btnCheckUpates.Visible = false;
                        btnUpdates.Visible = true;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception msg)
                {
                    lblServerMsg.Text = "No Updates are Found: " + msg.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            lblServerMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

> Above code i have done Get latest File from Source Folder but i dont no how to

```
var myFile = (from f in directoryServer.GetFiles()
                                      orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                                      select f).First();
```

> Above doe myFile are latest File from Source Folder this i want to copy into Destination Folder